# large file delete rows python

Tags: python, csv

Need some help with a use case. I have two file one is about 9GB (test_data)  and the other 42MB(master_data). test_data contains data with several columns one of the column i.e. #7 contains email address . master_data is my master data file which has just one column which is email address only.
What I am trying to achieve is to compare the emails in master_data file with the emails in test_data if they match, the whole row is to be deleted. I need an efficient way to achieve the same.

The below piece of code is written to achieve but I am stuck at deleting the lines from master_data file but am not sure if this is an efficient way of achieving this requirement.

```
import csv
import time
# open the file in read mode
filename = open('master_data.csv', 'r')

# creating dictreader object
file = csv.DictReader(filename)

# creating empty lists
email = []

# iterating over each row and append
# values to empty list
for col in file:
    email.append(col['EMAIL'])

# printing lists
print('Email:', email)

datafile = open('test_data.csv', 'r+')
for line in datafile:
    #print(line)
#    str1,id=line.split(',')
    split_line=line.split(',')
    str1=split_line[7] # Whatever columns
    id1=split_line[0]
    for w in email:
        print(w)
        print(str1)
        #time.sleep(2.4)
        if w in str1:
            print(id1)
            datafile.remove(id1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could load the master file and store the emails in a dict, then as you iterate the rows of test, you can check if the email for a row is in that (master) dict.

Given these CSVs:

- test.csv:

  ```
  Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7
  1,,,,,,foo@mail.com
  2,,,,,,bar@mail.com
  3,,,,,,baz@mail.com
  4,,,,,,dog@mail.com
  5,,,,,,foo@mail.com
  ```
- master.csv:

  ```
  Col1
  foo@mail.com
  cat@mail.com
  dog@mail.com
  ```

When I run:

```py
import csv

emails: dict[str, None] = {}

with open("master.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)  # skip header

    for row in reader:
        emails[row[0]] = None

out_line = "{:<20} {:>8}"

with open("test.csv", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)  # skip header

    print(out_line.format("Email", "Test ID"))
    for row in reader:
        if row[6] in emails:
            print(out_line.format(row[6], row[0]))
```

I get:

```
Email                 Test ID
foo@mail.com                1
dog@mail.com                4
foo@mail.com                5
```

That proves that you can read the emails in from master and compare with them while reading from test.

As others have pointed out, actually deleting anything from a file is difficult; it's far easier to create a new file and just exclude (filter out) the things you don't want:

```py
f_in = open("test.csv", newline="")
reader = csv.reader(f_in)

f_out = open("output.csv", "w", newline="")
writer = csv.writer(f_out)

for row in reader:
    if row[6] in emails:
        continue

    writer.writerow(row)

f_in.close()
f_out.close()
```

Iterating your CSV reader and writing-out with your CSV writer is a very efficient means of transforming a CSV (test.csv → output.csv, in this case): you only need the memory to hold `row` in each step of the loop.

When I run that, after having populated the emails dict like before, my output.csv looks like:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7
2,,,,,,bar@mail.com
3,,,,,,baz@mail.com
```

For the real-world performance of your situation, I mocked up a 42MB CSV file for master—1.35M rows of 32-character-long hex strings. Reading those 1.35M unique strings and saving them in the dict took less than 1 second real time and used 176 MB of RAM (on my M1 Macbook Air, with dual-channel SSD).

Also, I recommend using the csv module every time you need to read/write a CSV.  No matter how simple the CSV looks, using the csv readers/writers will be 100% correct and there's almost 0 overhead compared to trying and manually split or join on a comma.

Comment: I tied your soltion but it just prints Email", "Test ID" does nothing more than that.

Comment: Did you run it with my sample master.csv and test.csv files? The program is coded specifically for those columns. If your columns are different, you'll need to adapt the code. But as a first step, if you haven't already, copy my CSV and run the program again and try to get the print-out for "foo" and "dog" to show that matching works. I've also updated the answer to show how to get a new CSV without matches, you should also be able to get my output.csv, again, provided you start with my master.csv and test.csv data. Good luck! :)

Comment: please can you post the entire code you tested, i believe i am missing on my indents which is causing the issue at my end.

Comment: Just copy-paste those blocks of code, the first above the second, and don't add any extra indent. [image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7Bi8.png).

Comment: thanks zach, but is there a way to improve this. I am running the script for the last 16 hours still not yet completed. for me it looks like onl 22% is completed. by checking the master file

Answer (score 0):

Removing lines from a file is difficult. Its a lot easier to write a new file, filtering out rows as you go. Put your existing emails in a set for easy lookup, write to a temporary file and rename when done. This also has the advantage that you don't loose data if something goes wrong along the way.

You'll need to "normalize" the email. Most email systems are case-insensitive and ignore periods in addresses. Addresses can also contain extra name information as in `John Doe <j.doe@Gmail.com>`. Write a function that puts addresses into a single form and use it for both of your files.

```
import csv
import os
import email.utils

def email_normalize(val):
    # discard optional full name. lower case, remove '.' in local name
    _, addr = email.utils.parseaddr(val) 
    local, domain = addr.lower().split('@', 1)
    local = local.replace('.', '')
    return f'{local}@{domain)'

# create set of user emails to keep
with open('master_data.csv', newline='') as file:
    emails = set(email_normalize(row[0]) for row in csv.reader(file))

with open('test_data.csv', newline='') as infile, \
        open('test_data.csv.tmp', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(next(reader)) # write header
    writer.writerows(row for row in reader
        if email_normalize(row[7]) not in emails) # email is column #7
    del reader, writer

os.rename('test_data.csv', 'test_data.csv.deleteme')
os.rename('test_data.csv.tmp', 'test_data.csv')
os.remove('test_data.csv.deleteme')
```

Comment: i tried your solution , but i get the below error  I tried your soluton but i get the below error  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/itadmin/forum/1.py", line 14, in <module>
    emails = set(email_normalize(row[0]) for row in csv.reader(file))
  File "/home/itadmin/forum/1.py", line 14, in <genexpr>
    emails = set(email_normalize(row[0]) for row in csv.reader(file))
  File "/home/itadmin/forum/1.py", line 8, in email_normalize
    local, domain = addr.lower().split('@', 1)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: i checked a couple of lines in the data it , there are some blank emails or some emails without @ how to remove ignore this

Comment: You could catch the exception or test for `@` before the split. If the email isn't valid, what should happen with the data?

Comment: You may want to scrub the data before this processing.